# How to receive multiple intents to a single activity from different activities?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android development.
In my application I have a broadcast receiver R and 4 other activities, say A,B,C,D. When R received a SMS, R sends some data to A, B and C activities using intents. Sending data for those 3 activities works fine. Using sent data for A,B and C activities they implement their own tasks and produce some results. Now each of those A,B and C activities should send the produced results to Activity D. 
I used intents to implement this and data is sent as bundles. What I expect is activity D collects all the sent data(results) from A, B and C and display those in a single Text view. But what is being displayed on the Text view is, only the result made by Activity C and two null values. 
So, if you know how to overcome this issue please help me. It will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `I am new to android development.`

Your question sounds to me that you're missing some really big points in how the Android framework works.

There's always only ONE activity on the foreground and considering that the activity is processed by the UI thread, there's always just one activity being processed. That way, how do you "send it" to three activities? You can only start ONE!

Comment: It is close to impossible to guess what the problem is without the actual code. Share your code.

Comment: You need to show some code but, you are doing this in completely the wrong way.  Activities should not be used as classes to do processing.  Activities are for building and maintaining the app UI.

Comment: Well I'll provide some code.. Thanks for your attention on my thread..

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, maybe you are using a wrong approach.

Anyway, if you are sure about what you are doing (and if i understood correctly your problem), you could declare your activity as *singleInstance* or *singleTask*
See android:launchMode here for more details: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

I'd like to hilight that the documentation itself says

> The other modes — singleTask and singleInstance — **are not
>   appropriate for most applications**, since they result in an
>   interaction model that is likely to be unfamiliar to users and is very
>   different from most other applications.

---

EDIT:

After reading your code:
There are 2 possible ways to solve this problem

If you do **NOT** need user interaction, you should use an AsyncTask (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html): you do not need activities just to perform calculations and you should not use them in this way.
If you want to be sure that every task has been completed before proceding, you might want to use an Executor. Add the tasks (`new AsyncTaskClassX().executeOnExecutor(executor, params);`) and then, if you want to wait for results:

```
executor.shutdown();
try {
    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //something
}
```

This will cause the system to wait for the completion of ALL tasks before proceding.

If you **NEED** user interaction then you may consider launching activities using

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Using this method you launch the first activity (that takes control of the screen), when the activity has completed its operations using something like

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

You can gather the result overriding `onActivityResult` and checking the request code you can establish wich activity just finished. At this point launch B then C and use their results.

*Just a note: you should have edited your question to add the code instead of add a comment. This avoids confusion when reading "complex" questions and keep everything in one place (this is also why i edited my answer and i did not added another answer).*

Comment: Thanks for your comment Barkausen, I have provided a detailed description with some code snippet. Could you explain what's wrong with it please?

Comment: Sorry Barkausen, I have to wait up to 8hours to answer my own question since I am new to this site. I'll provide for sure.. Thanks again for your kind attention.

Comment: Thank you very much Barkausen for your knowledge and advises. Those are really important for me. Finally i found a solution for my problem. Instead of having 3 separate activities I used a single activity which contains the code of those 3 activities. Now the code looks little bit longer and messy, but it works fine and provides desired results...

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution (:

Answer (score 1):

Activities are usually associated with UI. You can not have 3 activities running at the same time, since they are paused when another one gets on top.

If the process that the three (A,B,C) activities are doing doesn't require UI, i would move it to a Service or Thread, and have it report back to the D activity using a broadcast intent.

If it does require UI, you will have to do it sequentially to ensure that the activity is not interrupted with another of your own activities. So, launch activity A, fill a new intent with it's result, and start activity B. Then B would calculate its own thing, put it together with A's result in a new intent a start C. Same thing with C activity, until it delivers all results to activity D.

I would definitely recommend you to read through the activity lifecycle documentation.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge Mr. Robert Estvill. I earlier tried the sequential way you specified, but it didn't work. But now I found a solution for this. Instead of having three separate activities I am using a single activity which includes the code snippets of all three activities. Although the new code looks somewhat messy, it works fine and provides the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
splitMsg = smsMsg.split("\\n");

for(int i=0; i<splitMsg.length; i++)
{
  if(!(splitMsg[i].equalsIgnoreCase("null")))
  {
     splitFeatures = splitMsg[i].split(":");               

     if(splitFeatures[0].equals("SomethingToA"))
     {

       String valueA = splitFeatures[1];
       b.clear();
       b.putString("keyA", valueA);

       Intent ia = new Intent(context, A.class);
       iaContactName.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       iaContactName.putExtras(b);
       context.startActivity(ia);  
     } 

     if(splitFeatures[0].equals("somethingToB"))
     {
       String valueB = splitFeatures[1];
       b.clear();
       b.putString("keyB", valueB);   
       Intent ib = new Intent(context, B.class);
       ib.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

       ib.putExtras(b);
       context.startActivity(ib);
     } 

     if(splitFeatures[0].equals("SomethingToC"))
     {
       String valueC = splitFeatures[1];
       b.clear();
       b.putString("keyC", unreadSms);

       Intent ic = new Intent(context, C.class);
       ic.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       ic.putExtras(b);
       context.startActivity(ic);
     } 
   }
 }
```

Now above code snippet is the part I have used to send data from R receiver to activities A,B and C. Each of those 3 activities receives appropriate intent which has been sent to them and will extract the bundled data and use those data to produce some results.

Then the produced results will be bundled and sent to the activity D. This is how 
it's done.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
 b.putString("keyD", valueD);
 Intent id = new Intent(A.this,D.class);
 id.putExtras(b);
 startActivity(id); 
 Each of A,B and C activities send results to D as in the above. Then D will try to  
 extract data from intents as like this, 

   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();



if(extras != null)
   {
      String fromA = extras.etString("keyA");           
      String fromB = extras.etString("keyB");           
      String fromC = extras.etString("keyC");       
      // some code goes here to append fromA, fromB, fromC together and set it into a 
         Text view. 
     }
```

But in the text view, it displays something like this,
     "null
      null
       result produced by activity C"

instead of,
  "result produced by activity A

result produced by activity B

result produced by activity C"